# Jquery not working to hide and show div until Bootstrap tab clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 different divs that need to appear depending on which tab is active.

If tab "#myTab class overview" is active then the "rental div" should show. If "#myTab class overview" is not active them the "homeo div" should show.

My function does not work on page load, on page load both divs appear. If i click either tab then only does my function work.

Do you know how to get my function to be working on page load.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                if ($("#myTab")[0].className=='overview active')
                    jQuery('#rental').show(), jQuery('#homeo').hide(); 
                else
                    jQuery('#rental').hide(), jQuery('#homeo').show();
                    
            });
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rental">
<a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-lg blue" role="button">DOWNLOAD APPLICATION</a>
</div>


<div id="homeo">
<a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-lg blue" role="button">Test</a>
</div>

 
 
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li id="myTab" class="overview active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">RENTAL</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homeowner">HOMEOWNER</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: created jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/cnsLfbza/

Comment: This is correct jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/cnsLfbza/4/

Answer (score 3):

Why not use CSS or style attribute to hide the element on pageload. Suppose you want to only show rental at page load

```
<div id="homeo" style="display:none;">
<a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-lg blue" role="button">Test</a>
</div>
```

Or with CSS

```
#homeo {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.className` is native javascript. jQuery objects don't have this property.

You want to use `$("#myTab")[0].hasClass('overview')`

[jQuery hasClass documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your hide/show code on page load alongwith tab click as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            if($('#myTab').hasClass('overview active'))
            {
                jQuery('#rental').show(), jQuery('#homeo').hide();
            }else
            {
                jQuery('#rental').hide(), jQuery('#homeo').show();
            }
            jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                if ($("#myTab")[0].className=='overview active')
                    jQuery('#rental').show(), jQuery('#homeo').hide(); 
                else
                    jQuery('#rental').hide(), jQuery('#homeo').show();

            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is with demo

https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/cnsLfbza/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            if($('#myTab').hasClass('overview active'))
            {
                jQuery('#rental').show(), jQuery('#homeo').hide();
            }else
            {
                jQuery('#rental').hide(), jQuery('#homeo').show();
            }
            jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
                if ($("#myTab")[0].className=='overview active')
                    jQuery('#rental').show(), jQuery('#homeo').hide(); 
                else
                    jQuery('#rental').hide(), jQuery('#homeo').show();

            });
        }) 



<div id="rental">
<a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-lg blue" role="button">DOWNLOAD APPLICATION</a>
</div>


<div id="homeo">
<a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-lg blue" role="button">Test</a>
</div>



  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li id="myTab" class="overview active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">RENTAL</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#homeowner">HOMEOWNER</a></li>
  </ul>
```